# Discrete Logarithm of 1 (mod p)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Strangely there is no question about this anywhere on the internet or this site, SO I assume it is settled then...

Suppose I am given a modulus with prime index p, defined in the usual way. Just as an example, say modulo 23.

5 is a generator of the cyclic group $ \mathbb{Z}_{22}^* $, which is related to modulo 23. In that group, one can ask what the discrete logarithm is base 5 of 1, that is

$ dlog_5(1) \equiv $ ? (mod 23)

In the cyclic group it makes sense to say that it is simply the inverse of 5, I suppose. But I am confused how it makes sense in (mod 23), since there are not 22 elements in it. Specifically, the formula could be interpreted to mean:

$$ 5^0 \equiv 1 \equiv 5^{22} $$ (mod 23)

So is the discrete logarithm of 1 modulo 23 equal to 0 or 22? Or why is this a senseless question?

Comment: The discrete log is only defined up to multiples of 22, though it is conventional to insist on the unique answer that lies between 0 and 21.

Comment: I prefer $0$, for no good reason.

Comment: I guess due to a technical way I've tried to define it, I object to either. It seems to me that we want the discrete logarithm to satisfy the identity that it can be taken on both sides of a congruence, but the value of one baffles that since it can be either number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , then what is the discrete logarithm of 0? 0?

Comment: The discrete log of zero, like the ordinary log of zero, is undefined. I don't know what you mean by "it can be taken on both sides of a congruence".  $5^x\equiv5^y\bmod{23}$ if and only if $x\equiv y\bmod{22}$. Does it bother you that $e^{3\pi i/2}=e^{-\pi/2}=-i$, so $\log(-i)$ can be taken to be $3\pi i/2$ or $-\pi i/2$ (or more generally $3\pi i/2+2\pi ik$, $k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots$)? Ordinary log is a map from nonzero complex numbers to ${\bf C}/2\pi i$, discrete log is a map from mod 23 to mod 22.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have little experience with complex logarithms, so actually I don't have a good grasp on what you are saying and it does bother me a bit (lol). I am guess my confusion is that a discrete log maps (mod 23) to (mod 22), so the discrete log (mod 23) cannot be applied twice to the same number, a difference between it and real valued logarithms.

Comment: @GerryMyerson probably time for another question instead of just asking a million in the comments

Comment: If you insist on real-valued logarithms, they can't be applied twice, either. What's $\log\log(1/2)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $ log_2(log_2(1/2)) = log_2(-1) $. Good point.